# Ruby on rails: rake is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, asset-pipeline

When ever i try to run any rake test in my rails, it's give me error message "undefined method `whitelist_attributes". I'don't know why it's coming.

The error which i get is:

---

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for #  <Class:0x50de7d8>
  C:/Users/Arvind/project/book/config/initializers/devise.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>'
 C:/Users/Arvind/project/book/config/initializers/devise.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 C:/Users/Arvind/project/book/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     Tasks: TOP => environment
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)`enter code here`
```

---

My gem file look like this:

---

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'


   # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
   gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

   gem 'devise'
  gem 'protected_attributes'


  gem 'simple_form'
  gem 'state_machine', :git => 'https://github.com/seuros/state_machine.git'
  gem 'draper', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'js-routes'
  gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-    bootstrap-rails.git'
  gem 'will_paginate'
 gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
 gem 'private_pub'
 gem 'foreman'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git'
 gem 'font-awesome-less'
  gem 'faye'
   group :development do
   gem 'thin'
    end
  group :test do
    gem 'shoulda'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    end

  group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'log_buddy'
 end

  group :production do
     gem 'pg'
  end
    gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

     gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
   # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
   # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

  # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
 # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
  gem 'turbolinks'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

  # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

 # Use Unicorn as the app server
 # gem 'unicorn'

 # Use Capistrano for deployment
 # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

  group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger  console
   gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

   # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` defined in your `config/application.rb` file? If so, remove that line or set it to false: `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false`

Do you have `white_list_attributes` defined in your model classes? If so, remove those. Your should be using strong_parameters in 4.2.1. https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: I remove "config.active_record.whitelist_attributes" this from my config/application.rb. but don't have any "white_list_attributes". Still it's give same error

Comment: After installing Strong_parameters now i receive this error:- rake db:reset
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
C:/Users/Arvind/project/book/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Arvind/project/book/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: heroku run rake db:setup
Running `rake db:setup` attached to terminal... up, run.6684
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'........     NoMethodError: undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

Comment: hmm...you might need to set it to false. Might have to get a look at your config files to see what you have in there that is turning this on.